# angular how show file image (byte[])

Tags: angular

I receive `Byte[]` from a REST API. How can I show this `ByteArray` which is a file image in my front-end Angular 9
I tried to do that

```html
<img *ngIf="logo" src={{logo.image}} alt="" width="50" />
```

But obviously, it does not work

Comment: Giving the image is not huge, then converting array to data URL will be just fine. See [link](https://medium.com/@koteswar.meesala/convert-array-buffer-to-base64-string-to-display-images-in-angular-7-4c443db242cd)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to convert the byte array to a base64 string.

Please try this:

component.html

```html
<img *ngIf="logo" [src]="imgData" alt="" width="50" />
```

component.ts

```js
imgData = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(logo.image)));
```

Comment: error NG5002: Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 42 in [btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(logo.image)))]

Comment: ngAfterContentInit(): void{
    this.imgData = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(this.logo.image)));
  }  ===> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Comment: if i add on nginit no error but  no image

Comment: new Uint8Array(this.logo.image) create an empty object , if i print this.logo.image is very long string in front is type of  any but in java is bytes[]